# Inserting CSV data into MYSQL db using query

Tags: java, mysql, csv

I have a query for loading CSV file into DB
 `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'E:/GPA/IT2.csv' INTO TABLE gpatest.semesterone FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`

My query works well when i execute in query browser but when i implement this in java it doesn't work. I have attached my code below kindly guide me necessary changes. `

```
      String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/gpatest";
      Class.forName(myDriver);
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "root");
      String query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'E:/GPA/IT2.csv' INTO TABLE gpatest.semesterone FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';";

      Statement st = conn.createStatement();

      ResultSet rs =  st.executeQuery(query); 
      st.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

`

Comment: Try `'\\n'` instead of `'\n'` in your query .

Comment: "it doesn't work".  Any more details?

Comment: Thanks berger adding \ worked for me.

Comment: @Berger since your comment solved the question, could you convert it into a answer so the OP can accept it?

Comment: @KeithM : Sure why not !

Answer (score 1):

Use `\\n` instead of `\n` in your query:

```
String query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'E:/GPA/IT2.csv' INTO TABLE gpatest.semesterone FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';";
```

The explanation is that `\n` in a java `String` means "new line", if you want the literal "\n" you have to escape the backslash with another backslash (which is the escape character in a java `String` )